# Retrieving data returns none

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to retrieve all rows in mysql.

```
import mysql.connector,sys

user,pw, host,db = 'root','12345','127.0.0.1','CA2Database'
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

try:
    print(cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM student'))
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print(err)
    print("Error Code:", err.errno)
    print("SQLSTATE", err.sqlstate)
    print("Message", err.msg)
finally:
    print()
```

The output is `None` . There is data in the table.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XkA2.jpg

Comment: Where do you print the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you were missing some necessary function calls. This should do:

```
user,pw, host,db = 'root','12345','127.0.0.1','CA2Database'
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM student;'
cursor.execute(sql_query)
data = cursor.fetchall()

cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, but i got this error ```MySQLInterfaceError: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now```

Comment: Hi @Wolfeatspotatoes after you close the cursor if you want to run any more sql command you have to open it again like this: 
cursor = connection.cursor()

Comment: Got it! But now it returns ``` No result set to fetch from.
Error Code: -1
SQLSTATE None
Message No result set to fetch from.```. is the problem in my database?

Comment: are you calling cursor.fetchall() twice ? I think so. You can't do that.